# Writing xpath and CSS locator/path for Selenium Automated Test

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors, firebug

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="submit" style="-webkit-user-select:none;line-height:100%;height:30px" value="Advanced Search" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action adv-button">
```

I have written xpath as:  `//input[@value='Advanced Search']`

What is the CSS locator/path?

Comment: 15 questions and 0 accepted answers? You should accept some answers if they are right, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/163680 and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer as optimum search selectors need the entire source code to be written, as several DOM Elements in the document could be returned for a generic selector. 
In this case, a more detailed selector would be :

```
input.adv-button[value='Advanced Search']
```

Comment: I agree with Grooveek. Selenium IDE 1.8 recorded the xpath as:
    //input[@value='Advanced Search']
Selenium IDE recorded xpath is matched with mine that I read manually

Comment: Your selector is incorrect. Correct xpath: `//input[@value='Advanced Search' and contains(@class, 'adv-button')]`. Correct CSS: `input.adv-button[value='Advanced Search']`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your xpath into corresponding CSS Locator by using the following website:
    http://cssify.appspot.com/

For example:

1. Go to site http://cssify.appspot.com/
2. Insert the XPath  //input[@value='Advanced Search'] into text field
3. Click submit button and observe the result
4. You can see the corresponding CSS Locator as follows:
   input[value="Advanced Search"]

Comment: For some reason the site does not accept the following as a valid XPath:

//div[starts-with(@id,'menuPanel')]

Comment: @NestorDRod: You can use cssSelector in that case. Or, You can use absolute xpath.

Comment: Well, yes, but I thought the whole idea behind the cssify site is to help you convert your XPath statement to a CSS selector. My statement referred to the fact that cssify did not accept the path above as valid, even though Selenium IDE has no problem with it.